# Symfony : Testing email sending in command

Tags: php, symfony, email, command

Good morning.

I would like to test sending email in my Symfony Command.

My email is send with `\Swift_Mailer` by

```
$this->mailer->send($message);
```

I try to use this:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/testing.html

But `$this->client->getProfile()` and `Symfony Response` is not available in Symfony Command.

```
Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Profiler\Profiler::loadProfileFromResponse() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response, null given,
```

Now how can i verify that my email is send correctly?

Comment: Please provide some code samples of what you've currently got...

Comment: if ($this->mailer->send($message))

Answer (score 4):

When testing commands you should have `$kernel` variable. From that you get container with `$kernel->getContainer()`. With container you have access to message logger: `$container->get('swiftmailer.mailer.default.plugin.messagelogger')`. That's is. Now you have an instance of `Swift_Plugins_MessageLogger` which have `#getMessages` which returns sent messages.

Comment: Note: this solution requires that you set `swiftmailer.logging: true` in your config

Answer (score 2):

You can put the spool type of swiftmailer to file and then count the files in that path.

In symfony4 it could be:

test/swiftmailer.yaml

```
 swiftmailer:
    spool:
        type: file
        path: 'path/to/emailTestFolder'
```

Test file

```
$mails = new \FilesystemIterator('path/to/emailTestFolder', \FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$this->assertSame(1, iterator_count($mails));
```